# How do i open netedit after installing sumo by the terminal?

Tags: command-line

I need to create my own network for simulation but i need netedit that built on top of the sumo netconvert. How do I do it. Do I need anything else besides sumo?

Answer (score 3):

After you've installed `sumo`, in the terminal, you type `netedit`.

Answer (score 0):

Or you click the following

RightClick Ubuntu>Applications>Edit Menus
 
Education (enter menu)
New Item
Type: Application
Name: Netedit
Command: netedit %F
Comment: SUMO Network Editor
OK
Move Up/Down to your liking
Close

And you have forever a nice Netedit to click near Sumo in the Education menu

Windows users must understand "where shall we put the shortcuts?"
Linux users must understand that they have to find them, if any
Repeat the above if none

Note: this is a local menu entry (only for your username)
global menu entries (for all users) are possible but more complicated